# Cannot navigate to @sample tag

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-dokka

In standard library of Kotlin we have `Preconditions.kt` that uses `@sample` tag:

```
/**
 * Throws an [IllegalStateException] if the [value] is false.
 *
 * @sample samples.misc.Preconditions.failCheckWithLazyMessage
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun check(value: Boolean): Unit {
```

Is it possible to make this tag usable in IntelliJ? I mean to see the content of `samples.misc.Preconditions` in-place or make it navigable. I wasn't able to find any dependency that should be added to classpath to make it working.

Comment: What do you mean by usable? [`sample` is one of the built in KDoc block tags](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html#block-tags).

Comment: In other words: is it possible to see the samples that are marked with @Sample annotation?